# Search and Count number of occurrences of a specific text in JSON file

Tags: python, json, count, find-occurrences

would love some help please.

I am trying to write a script to search a JSON file and count the number of occurrences of multiple groups of text.

This is what i have so far. Just trying to count 1 to start with. In the end i would love to be able display the counts in list format.
For example, something like this...

Diamond 7
Gold 5
Iron 45

```
When i run the below script the cmd flashes up and immediately dissappears.

Many thanks!


    import json
    f = open('_metadata.json')
    data = json.load(f)
    total_len = len(data)
    n = 0
    count = 0
    while n < total_len:
        if data[n]['status'] == "Diamond":
            count += 1
    
        if n == total_len-1:
            break
        n += 1

     print("Diamond : %s" % count)
     input('Press ENTER to exit')


thanks!
```

Comment: need sample json file.

Comment: You have indentation errors (making the code shown syntactically incorrect). How you fix them will affect the logical flow

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try and attach a screenshot to show how i have it in pycharm.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRH15.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRH15.png)